# proof by contrapositive if $x^2(y^2-2y)$ is odd, then $x$ and $y$ are both odd

Tags: proof-writing, solution-verification

proof by contrapositive,

prove if $x^2(y^2-2y)$ is odd, then $x$ and $y$ are both odd

**Attempt**

The contrapositive of the given statement is if $x$ or $y$ even then $x^2(y^2-2y)$ is even

so then I considered three cases

Case 1, Assumed $x$ even and $y$ is odd then proved $x^2(y^2-2y)$ is even

Case 2, Assumed $y$ even and $x$ is odd then proved $x^2(y^2-2y)$ is even

Case3, Assumed $x$ even and $y$ is even then proved $x^2(y^2-2y)$ is even

Then I said contrapositive statement is true and so given statement is true

Is my proof correct?

Comment: Well, we don't have any details of your proof so we can't tell if it is correct or not.  The logic looks ok, though it's simpler to just look at two  overlapping cases, $x$ even and $y$ even.  Since your number is divisible by $xy$ the product is obviously even in both of those two cases.

Comment: @lulu actually I want to know whether my logic is correct or not?

Comment: As I say, the logic is ok but it could be simplified.  You introduce three cases where two will suffice.  Of course, each case is quite easy so it's not a big problem.

Comment: @lulu thank you I got it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need three cases, just two: in your first case, you don't use at all the assumption that $y$ is odd and similarly in the second case.

- If $x$ is even, then $x^2(y^2-2y)=x\bigl(x(y^2-2y)\bigr)$ is even.
- If $y$ is even, then $x^2(y^2-2y)=y\bigl(x^2(y-2)\bigr)$ is even.

Your logic is fine, of course, but the aim of exercises of this kind is to test your skill at applying hypotheses when making deductions. While you certainly may at first consider the three cases, when attacking the problem, but then you *should* realize that two cases are enough.

Comment: Got it thank you